# I want to navigate from a uiviewcontroller to the uitabbarcontroller Programmatically in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, navigation, uitabbarcontroller

I want to naviagate from a controller(that is not part of the uitabbarcontroller) to the uiviewcontroller(that is part of the uitabbarcontroller) How can i acheive this?

Comment: Can you show your design? Then it will be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    let tabBar = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourTabBarStoryboardId") as! UITabBarController
    self.present(tabBar, animated: true) {
        //This selected index will be the index of your view controller you want to present
        tabBar.selectedIndex = 1
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: schema]

### Using storyboard segue

Set segue between your `UIViewController` and `UITabBarController` and perform it.

---

### Programmatically

Just present new instance of certain `UITabBarController` with controllers

```
let tabBarController = // instantiate it (add controllers if needed)
present(tabBarController, animated: true)
```

---

**Instantiate from storyboard**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let instantiated = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifier")
if let tabBarController = instantiated as? UITabBarController {
    present(tabBarController, animated: true)
}
```

**Subclass of `UITabBarController` with instantiate method for nib**

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    class func instantiate(with controllers: [UIViewController]) -> TabBarController {
        let controller = TabBarController(nibName: "TabBarController", bundle: nil)
        controller.viewControllers = controllers
        return controller
    }

}
```

Usage (don't forget to set `UITabBarItem` of each controller):

```
present(TabBarController.instantiate(with: controllers), animated: true)
```